# How to convert referencenode to GameScene coordinate?

Tags: ios, swift

Now there is a problem, when I add `spritenode` directly to `gamescene`, it can show emitter, but if add `ShoseCo.sks` to `GameScene.sks`, the emitter could not be shown?

(GameScene.sks -> ShoseCo.sks -> SpriteNode(vansShose))

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Here r the screenshot below

一、GameScene.swift

[GameScene add a ShoseCo.sks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQBD7.png)

[GameScene.swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22E8G.png)

二、ShoseCol.sks

[shoseCol.sks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUnkY.png)

三、Shose.swift

[Shose.swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16XnM.png)